# Upload image with RESTSharp (addFile)

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, rest, azure, restsharp

I'd like to send a picture from my Windows Phone on a webservice hosted on Windows Azure.
To communicate with my service, I use RESTSharp and I saw that there was a method named addFile for sending file.

```
RestRequest request;
request = new RestRequest("/report/add", Method.POST);

request.AddFile("test", ConvertToBytes(e.ChosenPhoto), "testfile");
App.Client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
    RestResponse resource = response;
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your report has been sent! Thank you for your participation!");
    }
});
```

However, I do not know how to retrieve the array of bytes sent when the request arrives at the service.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Could you show the code that you use to handle the file server side? It could be that you're looking in the wrong place.

Alternatively, you could try an other way to add the file:

```
request.AddBody(new { myFile = fileByteArray }))
```

**Note:** In both cases the file will be loaded in memory. This could be a problem for large files.

Comment: My problem is I do not know how to retrieve the file to the web service. How can I retrieve the value sent with AddBody (variable name)?

Comment: How did you create the web service? Is it WCF (REST)? ASP.NET MVC? ASP.NET MVC Web API? PHP? ...

Comment: I solved my problem with this video : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/windowsazure/learn/Using-Windows-Azure-Storage-on-Windows-Phone (so, without webservice)

Comment: you should sum up what you did in another answer